# Corrupted image using PIL Image.paste()

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

**Image gets corrupted when usin PIL.Image.Image.paste() method**

I'm trying to paste this plot

[image: plot.png]

on the following background

[image: background.png]

But, when running the following code I get an image (out_image.png) where the plot looks corrupted.

```
from PIL import Image

BACKGROUND = 'background.png'
PLOT = 'plot.png'
OUT = 'out_image.png'

a = 51
b = 654

im = Image.open(BACKGROUND)
plot = Image.open(PLOT)

im.paste(plot, box=(a, b, a+plot.size[0], b+plot.size[1]), mask=plot)
im.save(OUT)
```

The following is the final output:

[image: out_image.png]

As you can see the plot axes look kind of transparent and the plotted line isn't red anymore, but a very light blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work try to convert into RGB

```
from PIL import Image

BACKGROUND = 'background.png'
PLOT = 'plot.png'
OUT = 'out_image.png'

a = 51
b = 654

im = Image.open(BACKGROUND).convert('RGB')
plot = Image.open(PLOT)

im.paste(plot, box=(a, b, a+plot.size[0], b+plot.size[1]), mask=plot)
im.save(OUT)
```